# Конвертация PX в EM

Tags: шрифты, html, css, вёрстка

```
<html>
    <body>      
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="article">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text and typesetting industry.</p>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

html, body  {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    h1  {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    h2  {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    p  {
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }
    #wrapper  {
        width: 1000px;
    }
    #article  {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 30px 30px;
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }
```

Всем добрый день! Возник вопрос о конвертации с `PX` на `EM`. Видел, много хороших сайтов используют `EM`.

Как конвертировать - пример(см. выше)?

Расскажите, как вы используете?

Буду благодарен за любую информацию!

*перед кодом подключаю обнуление всех стилей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сайт [pxtoem.com](http://pxtoem.com/)  специализируется по этой теме.

Comment: в boorbon sass mixins есть функция em(10px) - переводит 10px в em, недавно заметил что ее считают deprecated, кто может сказать почему?

Answer (score 1):

1 em = 16px

font-size: 12px; = font-size: 0.75em;

и т.д. :)

Comment: 1 em - это не 16px, а размер шрифта!

Answer (score 1):

Пользуюсь вот этим сайтом https://all-markup-news.com/px-to-em/ для конвертации

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/88240)

Comment: @Denis внимательнее, пожалуйста. Есть вероятность, что автору вопроса именно ссылка и была нужна.